# mod_ldap Apache error handling Server Error 500

Tags: apache, error-handling, mod-ldap

i have a working configuration of apache2-2.2.3-16.29.2 and mod_ldap. 
The users can log in and all requests are handled correct.

If a user tries to login and the user is not configured in LDAP a Server Error 500 is thrown.

In the apache error log there are two entries:

```
[13257] auth_ldap authenticate: user myuser authentication failed; URI /page [User not found][No such object]
[crit] [client x.x.x.x] configuration error:  couldn't check user.  No user file?: /page
```

So everything works fine. My question is: Is it possible that i can configure a 401 Error to be thrown instead of a 500?

Thanks and greetings from Nürnberg, 
Marco

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
```

More possible issue you may found on URL https://gitlab.com/dpenezic/small-admin-tips/blob/master/httpd-ldap.md